# typ3 content element header render as h1

Tags: html, typescript, typo3

I'm using typo3 7.6.3 and have a problem with the content element header.

It's rendered as

```
 <h2>
```

Tag, but I want to render it as

```
<h1>
```

Tag

Whats the correct TypoScript to do that?

Thanks!

Constants

```
content.defaultHeaderType = 1
```

setup

```
page = PAGE
page {
  config.simulateStaticDocuments = 0
   config.baseURL = http://www.domain.de/
   config.tx_realurl_enable = 1

  config.doctype = html5
  meta.author = domain.de
  meta.publisher = domain.de
  meta.keywords = eins zwei
  meta.description = domain.de text
  meta.revisit-after = 7 days
  meta.robots = all
  meta.rating = general
  meta.viewport = width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1
  meta.PAGE-TOPIC = Information
  meta.PAGE-TYPE  = Information

  shortcutIcon = fileadmin/design/images/favicon.png

  includeCSS {
    screen1 = fileadmin/design/css/bootstrap.css
    screen1.title = display
    screen1.media = screen 

  screen2 = fileadmin/design/css/style.css
  screen2.title = display
  screen2.media = screen 

  screen3 = fileadmin/design/css/font-awesome.min.css
 screen3.title = display
  screen3.media = screen 

}

includeJS {
file1 = fileadmin/design/js/jquery-2.2.0.min.js
file2 = fileadmin/design/js/bootstrap.min.js
}

}

page.20 = TEMPLATE
page.20.template = FILE
page.20.template.file = fileadmin/design/index.html
page.20.marks{
CONTENTLEFT < styles.content.getLeft
CONTENTLEFT.renderObj.stdWrap.dataWrap=<div class="col-md-6">|</div>

CONTENTRIGHT< styles.content.getRight
CONTENTRIGHT.renderObj.stdWrap.dataWrap=<div class="col-md-6">|</div>

CONTENT < styles.content.get
CONTENT.renderObj.stdWrap.dataWrap=<div class="col-md-12">|</div>



MENU = HMENU
MENU.entryLevel = 0
#NAVIMAIN.excludeUidList = 

MENU {
1 = TMENU
1 {
expAll = 1

NO.allWrap = <li>|</li>
NO.ATagTitle.field = abstract // description // title

ACT = 1
ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>
ACT.ATagTitle.field = abstract // description // title

IFSUB = 1
IFSUB.before = <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
IFSUB.after =  <b class="caret"></b></a>
IFSUB.doNotLinkIt = 1
IFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="dropdown">|</li>
IFSUB.ATagTitle.field = abstract // description // title

ACTIFSUB = 1
ACTIFSUB.before = <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data- toggle="dropdown">
ACTIFSUB.after =  <b class="caret"></b></a>
ACTIFSUB.doNotLinkIt = 1
ACTIFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="dropdown active">|</li>
ACTIFSUB.ATagTitle.field = abstract // description // title

wrap = <ul class="nav navbar-nav">|</ul>
}

   2 = TMENU
 2 {
expAll = 1

ACT = 1
ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>
ACT.ATagTitle.field = abstract // description // title

ACTIFSUB = 1
ACTIFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = |
ACTIFSUB.before = <li class="divider"></li><li class="nav-header">
ACTIFSUB.after = </li>
ACTIFSUB.doNotLinkIt = 1
ACTIFSUB.ATagTitle.field = abstract // description // title

NO.allWrap = <li>|</li>
NO.ATagTitle.field = abstract // description // title

IFSUB = 1
IFSUB.before = <li class="divider"></li><li class="nav-header">
IFSUB.after = </li>
IFSUB.doNotLinkIt = 1
IFSUB.ATagTitle.field = abstract // description // title

SPC = 1
SPC.allWrap = <li class="divider"></li><li class="nav-header">|</li>

wrap = <ul class="dropdown-menu">|</ul>
}

}
}
```

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

in css_styled_content/static i found this:
[image]

[image]

**UPDATE 3**
[image]

Comment: "_It's rendered as Tag, but I want to render it as Tag_" ???

Comment: sorry was hided by stackoverflow, I've added it as code see above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **TypoScript** template in the **Constants** field you have the line like:

```
content.defaultHeaderType = 2
```

which determines the ***default*** header as `H2`, definitely that was set by somebody, as default value is `H1`.

If that's not the clue that means that somebody interfered the CSS Styled Content even more, you just need to preview TypoScript template(s) and search for the place where it's done.

Comment: thats what I already tried, my constants are empty at the moment. Which templates do I have to check? my own one?

Comment: I've added my tpyoscript above

Comment: yes of course I deleted the cache about 1000 times, how do I check this: Check all templates available in the path, also these on subpages

Comment: I've added my post with Update2 can you please check up if this could be the problem?

Comment: I'm asking for Header, Screen what I mean is updated in my first post

Comment: Well I have no idea what's wrong, I've clear instalation of 7.6.3 (no bootstrap ext, no Indtroduction ext), and headers are rendered with valid `Hx` you need to analyze whole TypoScript what can manipulate the TS, maybe some other ext does it, I cant help you anyway without access to the backend

Comment: Use the ``TypoScript Object Browser`` and the ``Template Analyzer`` to see the full template for each site.

Comment: @pgampe, that what I suggested to OP in first comments, needed delete them later to get some _commenting space_, his TS looks normal